# Why does a car battery make such violent sparks, yet it it's safe for me to touch both terminals?

Tags: electric-current, voltage, batteries

YouTube videos have assured me that it's safe to touch the terminals of a 12V AGM car battery with my bare hands. They even claimed it'd only be a tingle if I connected wires to the terminals and touched them to my tongue.

However, when replacing my 12V AGM car battery recently, there was a fairly loud, bright and violent spark when the negative terminal temporarily re-made contact with the car's negative terminal connector.

How harmful to my hand could it have been if my hand was holding that terminal while it sparked, and what specifically determines the heat/danger associated with such sparks?

Comment: Don’t believe YouTube videos. Do NOT touch the wires to your tongue.

Comment: @JonCuster +1 I would want to state, the same but: "do not touch anything related to electricity bare-handed" (even if it is "safe")

Comment: @WilliamMartens I'd certainly not take any risks. FYI this is the video of a guy licking his thumbs and touching both car battery terminals with the same hand, to make a point... https://youtu.be/--DyF4gU0zc?t=36

Comment: @AndrewParks agreed. +1

Comment: @JonCuster While I agree with the sentiment "Do not believe youtube videos", It would be safe given you have an average tongue resistance of 7000 ohms. 12V is just not enough to drive a harmful amount of current through the hands or tongue. (The insides of a human body on the other hand have less resistance)

Comment: @Obliv - given one can weld reasonably effectively with a car battery (sure, two are better, 3 about perfect), any slight misapplication and you have 100s of amps on your tongue. Not good…

Comment: "FYI this is the video of a guy licking his thumbs and touching both car battery terminals with the same hand, to make a point..." If you happen to have two cuts (or other form of open wounds) on both of your thumbs, you could create a relatively low resistance current path from thumb to thumb. That current path would pass a significant amount of current density rather directly through your heart and surrounding tissue (along with other body parts on the way from one thumb to the other thumb). So, if you unlucky be able to give yourself a nice little heart attack and die.

Comment: Not only is it the "current that kills," the killing potential also depends on the path the current takes through your body. Current traveling from your left thumb to your left foot is likely less dangerous than current traveling from your left thumb to your *right* foot, since the latter path is more likely to go via your heart. Similarly, thumb to thumb path is pretty bad. You can google for electrical engineering literature about electrocution if you are interested. Yes, 12V is fairly low, but it is the current that kills.

Comment: @hft great points, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only safe with respect to electric shock, because the battery voltage is too low to cause an electric shock under most conditions.

The potential harm to your hands is a burn injury due to $I^{2}R$ heating and the resulting high temperatures that can occur if, for example, the terminals are shorted by a conductive object you may be holding or in on your hand. A burn injury can also occur to your tongue if, somehow, your tongue shorted the terminals (though at the moment I can't imagine how).

> I'm unclear about how long it would take for the conductive object to
> heat? If there was short circuit with a spanner, how long until that
> becomes hot enough to burn me? If a metal ring on my finger completed
> a short circuit, would I instinctively pull my hand away long before
> it got hot enough to burn me?

A wrench (American for spanner) is pretty massive so it has a high heat capacity. It would take a while for its temperature to get high enough to cause a burn. Regarding the ring on your finger, you might be able to pull your hand away before it gets burned. But if the heat transfer rate to your skin is high enough, you may get burned before you sense the high temperature. That’s what happens if you accidentally touch an electric stove top. You get burned before you are able to sense the heat.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Bob - I'm unclear about how long it would take for the conductive object to heat? If there was short circuit with a spanner, how long until that becomes hot enough to burn me? If a metal ring on my finger completed a short circuit, would I instinctively pull my hand away long before it got hot enough to burn me?

Comment: @AndrewParks I've update my answer to answer your follow up question. Hope it helps.

Comment: "You get burned before you are able to sense the heat" - fantastic point, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A car battery can drive a *lot* of current through a low resistance connection, and that can make sparks, set things on fire, etc. The resistance of human skin is relatively high, so the car battery doesn't have the voltage required to drive a hazardous current through your hands. But don't wear a ring when working with a car battery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I'm unclear about two things: 1. If my finger was next to that spark when it happened - how much would it have hurt? Would it have caused burns? 2. Why does wearing a ring make any difference? I've seen photos of injuries from doing exactly that when changing a battery, but I'm unclear on why touching a metal wire to the skin is different than touching a metal wire to the ring, which in turn touches the skin

Comment: @AndrewParks You wouldn't have felt it, because the spark was an electrical discharge from the battery to the terminal, causing the metal itself to break down and spark briefly. You're basically safe to touch the battery all you like except with your insides (resistance is smaller inside us)

Comment: @Obliv wow, so if my finger was directly touching the parts of metal in the place where they violently sparked together, it'd only have been a scary noise but I would not have felt it? Why exactly is it that the spark would not have hurt?

Comment: @Andrew The spark is a (small) bit of hot plasma, so it could give you a (small) burn.

Comment: @AndrewParks The ring hazard is mostly that it can, by itself, conduct a large current (not through the body). It can get very hot doing this.

Comment: @JohnDoty That's true, the metal itself probably got really hot. The burn would be the only thing to worry about (Although it could be nasty)

Comment: You could quite safely touch the poles of the battery, if no conductive element connects them in an approximately short-circuit, that can make the element heat up, as an example when you inadvertently touch the poles with a spanner. Anyway, the most dangerous thing could be cleaning your underwear, since you could sh*t your pants with a sudden unexpected spark